# Needs some explanations on Qt::operator

Tags: qt, operator-overloading

I am a biginer to Qt and referring to some tutorials on implicit ans explicit sharing and I came across following article.

http://cdumez.blogspot.com/2011/03/implicit-explicit-data-sharing-with-qt.html

in the code section I was not able to understand the functionality of the following operator

```
Contact& Contact::operator=(const Contact& other) {
  d = other.d;
  return *this;
}
```

If some one could explain this what exactly this does and why it is there for in code it would be a great help.

Thanks guys.

~Tharanga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is [overloading the assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). That way, when he says

```
c2 = c1;
```

`c2.d` will be the same as `c1.d`.

It is not `Qt` specific. Also see this [long explanation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading).

Answer (score 1):

This operator is the [assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C++%29). It is used when you write:

```
Contact c1;
Contact c2;
c2 = c1;
```

In your case the assignment operator only copies the d member of contact so `c2.d` will be the same as `c1.d`

Comment: Actually, in your example, the copy constructor will be invoked.

Comment: Let me try to understand this. Contact is explicitly shared and its other properties (if there were to be any other public variables) but the shared pointer d is implicitly shared. and I really appreciate the replies..Thanks again

Comment: With this operator overload, when assigning a contact to an other, only the d member will be assigned. All other member will not change.